# Can a STP template be hidden from subsite creation page?

Tags: sharepoint, templates, moss

When a template is added using the add-template stsadm command, it becomes available to everyone when creating a subsite. Is there any way to make it only available when a site collection is being created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to site actions -> Site Settings -> view all site settings -> site templates and page layouts and remove the site template from the list of allowed items.

Gary Lapointe may also have made an stsadm extenstion for it; check [stsadm.blogspot.com](http://stsadm.blogspot.com)

Mauro Masucci
http://www.brantas.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

The url to the blog post mentioned above, for hiding the stp templates using the stsadm extention, is http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/08/set-available-site-templates.html

> Here’s an example of how to remove a template from the list of available templates for a site collection:
>
> > stsadm –o gl-removeavailablesitetemplate –url "http://intranet/" -template "WIKI#0" -lcid 1033 -resetallsubsites

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mauro. I was hoping for a **solution** which doesn't require going to every site collection, but it looks like there may not be one!

Answer (score 0):

Komrade,

stsadm.blogspot.com may be the answer again, you can list all the site collections and then using the command that edward posted to remove the site templates.  That might help make things a bit quicker!

Although, you should only have to do it once per site collection, all subsites (as far as I remember) inherit their settings from the parent site.